# JavaScript Sort function Output is different in Mozilla Firefox Compared to Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting, firefox, javascript-objects

Well I've an JavaScript array of Objects like below.

```
players = [{"player": "CR7", "status": false, "fullname": "Cristiano Ronaldo"},
 {"player": "NJR11", "status": false, "fullname": "Neymar Jr."},
 {"player": "SC11", "status": false, "fullname": "Sunil Chhetri"},
 {"player": "LM10", "status": true, "fullname": "Lionel Messi"},
 {"player": "SG19", "status": false, "fullname": "Sergio Aguero"}
];
```

Also I've used below method to sort the array. My intended result is something like Object with status is `true` should come first & rest of the Objects keeps the Order.

```
players.sort((p) => (p.status) ? -1 : 1);
```

It WORKS fine in Google Chrome like below.

```
         [{"player":"LM10","status":true,"fullname":"Lionel Messi"},
          {"player":"CR7","status":false,"fullname":"Cristiano Ronaldo"},
          {"player":"NJR11","status":false,"fullname":"Neymar Jr."},
          {"player":"SC11","status":false,"fullname":"Sunil Chhetri"},
          {"player":"SG19","status":false,"fullname":"Sergio Aguero"}
         ]
```

But in Mozilla Firefox & in Android default Browser, it comes like below which is NOT I Wanted.

```
        [{"player":"LM10","status":true,"fullname":"Lionel Messi"},
         {"player":"SG19","status":false,"fullname":"Sergio Aguero"},
         {"player":"SC11","status":false,"fullname":"Sunil Chhetri"},
         {"player":"NJR11","status":false,"fullname":"Neymar Jr."},
         {"player":"CR7","status":false,"fullname":"Cristiano Ronaldo"}
         ]
```

Why is it behaving differently in Firefox & What is the Solution to Work it just like Chrome??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically shuffling the array. It shuffles the way you expect it to sort in Chrome *by accident*. Your sorting doesnt work at all. `sort` takes two elements after all, that you have to compare:

```
players.sort((a, b) => b.status - a.status);
```

That is a short form of:

```
players.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.status === b.status) return 0; // order doesnt matter
  if(a.status) return -1; // only a has status, comes first
  if(b.status) return 1 // only b has status, comes first
});
```

Alternatively:

```
 players = [...players.filter(it => it.status), ...players.filter(it => !it.status)];
```

*could* be faster depending on the sort algorithm the engine uses.

Answer (score 2):

With boolean values, you need to sort reverse, because `true` is interpreted as `1` and `false` is zero.

For getting `true` values first, you need to subtract `b` from `a`.

```js
var players = [{ player: "CR7", status: false, fullname: "Cristiano Ronaldo" }, { player: "NJR11", status: false, fullname: "Neymar Jr." }, { player: "SC11", status: false, fullname: "Sunil Chhetri" }, { player: "LM10", status: true, fullname: "Lionel Messi" }, { player: "SG19", status: false, fullname: "Sergio Aguero" }];

players.sort((a, b) => b.status - a.status); true frist

console.log(players);
```

Another solution by taking the callback, you supplied.

```js
var players = [{ player: "CR7", status: false, fullname: "Cristiano Ronaldo" }, { player: "NJR11", status: false, fullname: "Neymar Jr." }, { player: "SC11", status: false, fullname: "Sunil Chhetri" }, { player: "LM10", status: true, fullname: "Lionel Messi" }, { player: "SG19", status: false, fullname: "Sergio Aguero" }],
    sortBy = p => p.status ? -1 : 1; // true first

players.sort((a, b) => sortBy(a) - sortBy(b));

console.log(players);
```